# How to process queue in "parallel" to keep process saturated?

Tags: node.js

I want to process a queue in the following manner:

- Queue is persisted in MongoDb (possibly with npm package "mongodb-queue")
- Several node processes can work on the same queue
- Tasks involves various i/o which takes between zero to a couple of seconds each
- Each node process should work on max  tasks concurrently

The node processes also services a simple web site (express). But there will be very few requests from the site. Most work will be done processing the queue

The goal is to be able to saturate each process better than if each process only could pop one
task at a time. Since the tasks involves quite a bit of waiting for external services I
think it would be a waste not to process them in "parallell" (I know it's not really in parallell). 
I'm thinking that five or so would be the limit, but this would have to be tweaked after a while.

Rough pseudo code:

```
loopForewer {
    popNextTaskFromQueue(function(task) {
        if(task && concurrentTasks <= limit) {
            concurrentTasks ++;
            processTask(task, function(err) {
                concurrentTasks --;
            })
        })
    }
}
```

How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance.
//Michael

---

edit:

I'll elaborate some about Pauls suggestion on async.parallelLimit and an attempt with async.queue. I hope it's ok to do this by editing my own question.

**async.parallelLimit:**

Actually, I don't see how this would fit the bill. But I'm kind of a beginner in Node and JavaScript and I might have missed something.

I can't see how I can keep the process saturated (i.e. filled with 5 tasks) without first getting all available tasks from the queue in MongoDB. But if I get all the tasks, all but five will be sitting waiting instead of being processed by another node process.

**async.queue:**

What do think about this?

```
q = async.queue.., 5) //create a queue with concurrency limit 5
dbQ = someQueueWithMongoStorage..

while(true) {
    nextTick(function() {
        if (!q.saturated) {
            dbQ.getTask(function(err, task) {
                if (task) q.push(task)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

- Is it ok to use a while(true) loop?
- Or should it be recursive?
- Do I need nextTick here? I'm worried that the loop will take over the event queue otherwise.
- Problem is that I'll hit the database very much when dbQ is empty. Should I add a timeout when dbQ is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I went on and tried the async.queue concept. I'll use (kind of) the below solution. Please chime in and tell me if I'm doing something stupid, i.e. locking something up. I'll hit the db every second when dbQ is empty, but that's fine with me.

```
var limit = 5;

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
        console.log('Processing ' + task.payload.task);
        setTimeout(function() {
            dbQ.ack(task.ack, function(err) {
                console.log('Finished ' + task.id);
                callback(); 
            })
        }, 1000);
}, limit);


function enqueueTasks() {
    console.log('QueueLength: ' + q.length() + ',  Running tasks: ' + q.running());
    if (q.length() < limit) {
        dbQ.get(function(err, task) {
            if (task) {
                console.log('Enqueing task ' + task.id)
                q.push(task, function(err) {

                });
                enqueueTasks();
            } else {
                console.log('dbQ is empty, taking a 1 second nap')
                setTimeout(function() {
                    enqueueTasks();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Queue length limit hit, taking a 1 second nap')
        setTimeout(function() {
            enqueueTasks();
        }, 1000);
    }
}

enqueueTasks();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `async` library, in particular the `parallelLimit` function.

https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback

Comment: Thanks. But with async.parallell i'd have to first fill an array with tasks. I.e. pop more tasks from the queue than i could handle (limit), thus making other node processes starving unnecessarily. I'm leaning towards async.queue. I could check if queue.length() < limit before poping from the mongodb queue.

Comment: Sure, either way would work. Not sure I agree that you'd 'starve' processes with my approach but `queue` works fine too.

Comment: I tried to describe my thoughts about your solution in a comment. But with no line breaks and small box to type in it was too hard. Can I go back to my question and elaborate about the solutions? I'm not sure what's ok in Stack Overflow terms.